# Learning to debug in Java

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, jpda

I'm both learning to use the JPDA on Netbeans and solving the [Prime Generator](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/) problem of Sphere's Online Judge.

I've been reading [this tutorial on netbeans.org](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/55/using-netbeans/debug.html) about he JPDA, but haven't found it of much help.

This code, which is based on a Sieve of Eratostenes implementation provided by starblue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers), is running like this:

```
2
1 10
//here the primes between 1 and 10 should print 
3 5
//here the primes between 3 and 5 should print 




package sphere;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
//import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{

  public static int ApproximateNthPrime(int nn)
{
    double n = (double)nn;
    double p;
    if (nn >= 7022)
    {
        p = n * Math.log(n) + n * (Math.log(Math.log(n)) - 0.9385);
    }
    else if (nn >= 6)
    {
        p = n * Math.log(n) + n * Math.log(Math.log(n));
    }
    else if (nn > 0)
    {
        p = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 }[nn - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        p = 0;
    }
    return (int)p;
}

// Find all primes up to and including the limit
public static BitSet SieveOfEratosthenes(int limit)
{
    final BitSet primes = new BitSet();
    primes.set(0,false); 
    primes.set(1,false); 
    primes.set(2,limit,true); 

    for (int i =0; i*i<limit;i++)
    {
        if (primes.get(i))
        {
            for (int j=i*1; j<limit;j+=1)
            {
                primes.clear(j);// hace que el indice j sea false (no primo)
            }

        }

    }
    return primes;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> GeneratePrimesSieveOfEratosthenes(int n)
{
    int limit = ApproximateNthPrime(n);
    BitSet bits = SieveOfEratosthenes(limit);
    ArrayList <Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0, found = 0; i < limit && found < n; i++)
    {
        if (bits.get(i))
        {
            primes.add(i);
            found++;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}





  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
     java.io.BufferedReader r = new java.io.BufferedReader (new java.io.InputStreamReader (System.in));
     String s;

     s= r.readLine();

     int test_cases = Integer.parseInt(s);


     int case_counter =0;

     while (case_counter<test_cases) {

        // System.out.println(s);
         s = r.readLine();

         String [] splitted = s.split(" ");

         int lower_bound = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
         int upper_bound = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);



        ArrayList <Integer> primesList=  GeneratePrimesSieveOfEratosthenes(upper_bound);



         for (int i =0; i<primesList.size();i++){
            if (primesList.get(i)<=lower_bound)System.out.println(primesList.get(i));
         }


         case_counter++;

         System.out.println(" "); // space that separates test cases

     }
  }
}
```

I know that the ArrayList primesList isn't getting initialized and I'm suspicious of this bit of code, cause honestly, I don't quite understand it:

```
if (primes.get(i))
        {
            for (int j=i*1; j<limit;j+=1)
            {
                primes.clear(j);
            }

        }
```

It occurred to me to use a conditional breakpoint here with the condition of:

```
primes.get(j)==false
```

But I'm not sure if I'm able to get meaningful info this way. These are the screens I'm getting:

[alt text http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/6238/breakpoints.jpg](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/6238/breakpoints.jpg)

[alt text http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/5262/watchesz.jpg](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/5262/watchesz.jpg)

I don't know how to get useful info out of this.

My questions are:

**a)I want to watch the primes BitSet as its going through this loop.**

**How do I do that?**

**b)** **What's exactly wrong with this code?** 
**How did you spot it using the debugger?**

**Please, mention the step-by-step process.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I extracted out the following method:

```
    private static void printPrimes(int lower_bound, int upper_bound) {
    ArrayList<Integer> primesList = GeneratePrimesSieveOfEratosthenes(upper_bound);

    for (int i = 0; i < primesList.size(); i++) {
        if (primesList.get(i) <= lower_bound)
            System.out.println(primesList.get(i));
    }
}
```

and changed the `main()` method to just call that with a couple of arbitrary arguments (10 and 100), because I didn't want to mess around with the console and the debugger at the same time. I then (I'm using Eclipse) put ordinary breakpoints at the beginning and end lines of `ApproximateNthPrime()`, `SieveOfEratosthenes()` and `GeneratePrimesSieveOfEratosthenes()` to make sure they were being called. (By the way, Java convention, unlike C#, is for method names to start with a lower-case letter.)

All that was without bothering to understand the code. :) However, after the first run-through, it was pretty clear that the problem is that the `BitSet` produced by `SieveOfEratosthenes()` is always empty (or rather, always entirely `false`). I haven't used the NetBeans debugger, but I suspect the "Local Variables" tab is your friend here.

I'm not going to do your homework for you. :) But the idea of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is to skip the prime numbers and only eliminate the non-primes. Examine your `SieveOfEratosthenes()` method and ask yourself: when will it skip a number?