# How does this regex find primes?

Tags: regex, primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if a number is a prime with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795065/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime-with-regex)

[This page](http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/) claims that this regular expression discovers non-prime numbers (and by counter-example: primes):

```
/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/
```

How does this find primes?

Comment: This is **not** a dup. It's a different regexp and a different technique, and has better answers, to boot.

Comment: @bmargulies: This *is* a dupe.  The regex is the same, given the input restrictions on this question and that Java's String.matches method matches the regex against the entire string (so ^ and $ are implied), which it apparently does.

Comment: @Rog - the upvoted answers over there never mention unary.

Comment: @bmargulies: If you believe you can provide a better or more complete answer to that question, please, do so.  I'd flag this question for merging, but the *superficial* differences in question text mean the answers need some editing (as is often the case), even though the questions are identical once you remove those superficial differences.

Comment: @Rog at this point I'll just trust the diamonds to merge cleverly.

Comment: `^(?!1?$|(11+?)\1+$)1+$` will find the actual primes, using a negative lookahead

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I think the article explains it rather well, but I'll try my hand at it as well.

Input is in [unary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system) form. 1 is `1`, 2 is `11`, 3 is `111`, etc. Zero is an empty string.

The first part of the regex matches 0 and 1 as non-prime. The second is where the magic kicks in.

`(11+?)` starts by finding divisors. It starts by being defined as `11`, or 2. `\1` is a variable referring to that previously captured match, so `\1+` determines if the number is divisible by that divisor. (`111111` starts by assigning the variable to `11`, and then determines that the remaining `1111` is `11` repeated, so 6 is divisible by 2.)

If the number is not divisible by two, the regex engine increments the divisor. `(11+?)` becomes `111`, and we try again. If at any point the regex matches, the number has a divisor that yields no remainder, and so the number cannot be prime.

Comment: Might be easier to follow: this is how the same regex would be written in [kleenexp](https://github.com/SonOfLilit/kleenexp) syntax: `[#start_line [ | '1' | [capture:factor 1+ '11'] [1+ #repeat:factor] ] #end_line]`

Comment: Check also https://mae.ufl.edu/~uhk/BINARY-OF-PRIME-NUMBERS.pdf