# Using regex to get title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, match

I'm not sure how I'd select an title with regex. I've tried

```
match(/<title>(.*) .*<\/title>/)[1]
```

but that doesn't match anything.

[This](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/1690978d4fce82455098a29ec2e9d5a2/raw/4da439e7c0ed090baa2706d9edca7ee17075391c/gistfile1.txt) is the response body I'm trying to select from.

Trying to select `"title I need to select."`

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexes only leads to unfortunate effects for the developer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392

Comment: "If you have a small set of HTML pages that you want to scrape data from and then stuff into a database, regexes might work fine." That seems like what I'm trying to do. So it might be fine?

Comment: Also what would you recommend doing instead?

Comment: @user3579614 do you have any familiarity with JavaScript? It's similar in syntax and more suited for scraping HTML pages.

Comment: Yeah a little bit. I've found nokogiri, that seems to do the job correctly?

Comment: @user3579614, Nokogiri is indeed the right tool for the job. Wrote an answer to explain how you can use it for your specific case.

Comment: @OneNeptune, I wouldn't say Ruby is unfit for html parsing. Nokogiri works as well as any other industry standard parser.

Comment: @ndn fair, I think highly of Ruby and just meant to suggest if it was a light weight utility not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: JavaScript is hardly more suitable for scraping, it's just different. A well implemented parser, like Nokogiri, is extremely powerful and convenient because it's designed for use with Ruby.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking a question like this, you should supply the minimal HTML necessary to demonstrate the problem. While this particular problem results in a small amount of HTML, future problems you ask about probably won't be as simple and that supplied data will be more important.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because of the `itemprop=\"name\"` property. To fix this, you can match it as well:

```
# copy-paste from the page you provided
html = '<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\" itemscope itemtype=\"https://schema.org/WebPage\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\"><meta name=\"referrer\" content=\"always\" />\n<title itemprop=\"name\">title I need to select.</title>\n<meta itemprop=\"description\" name=\"description\" content=\\'

html.match(/<title.*?>(.*)<\/title>/)[1] # => "title I need to select."
```

`.*?` basically means *"match as many characters are needed, but not more"*

---

However, as other have pointed out, regexes are not ideal for html parsing. Instead, you could use a popular ruby gem for that purpose - [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri):

```
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri.parse(html)
page.css('title').text # => "title I need to select."
```

Note that it can handle even malformed html like is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a much more robust XML/HTML parser, try using Nokogiri which supports XPath.

This post explains why
[Use xPath or Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059812/use-xpath-or-regex)

```
require "nokogiri"
string = "<title itemprop=\"name\">title I need to select.</title>"
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(string)
html_doc.xpath("//title").first.text
```

Comment: Better use CSS rather than Xpath, CSS is less error-prone.

Comment: I'm interested in an example of 'error prone'? The syntax for XPath is designed for XML mostly, but works with XHTML. CSS selectors can break just as easily with a CSS class/id change, XPath can break easily with the structure of the HTML breaking. Pick your posion in that regard. What makes CSS better other than the 'syntax is easier'?

Comment: `node.xpath("//foo")` does not select all `foo` descendants of `node`. About every other nokogiri question is someone tripping over that. I highly recommend CSS with its predictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regexp that will give you what you want:
`<title.*>(.*)<\/title>`

As was mentioned, there are better ways to parse HTML. You might want to check out something like [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html).

Comment: This will select a whole lot more if there are two `title` tags on that page.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to get elements from XML I like to convert it to a hash

> from_xml(xml, disallowed_types = nil) public
>
> Returns a Hash containing a collection of pairs when the key is the
>   node name and the value is its content
>
> # http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/from_xml/class

now you can do something like

```
hash = Hash.from_xml('XML')
hash.title # my favorite book
```

Comment: doesn't work for the OP's html, also you need to use rails or at least require 'active_support/all'

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the following pattern:

```
<title.*?>(.*?)<\/title>
```

https://regex101.com/r/piwm5H/1

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML/XML parser when dealing with XML or HTML data, except for extremely simple cases. HTML and XML are too complicated for normal regular expressions.

Using Nokogiri I'd do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

some_html = '
<html>
  <head>
    <title>the title</title>
  </head>
</html>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(some_html)
doc.title # => "the title"
```

Nokogiri already has a method to return the title so you can take advantage of that. Or, you can do it the normal way:

```
doc.at('title').text  # => "the title"
```

The problem with a regular expression is that HTML could be written in many ways:

```
<title>foo</title>
```

or:

```
<title>
  foo
</title>
```

or even:

```
<title>foo
</head>
```

which, while not correct, will be accepted by browsers and fixed up by Nokogiri which will then still work. Writing a pattern to handle those variants is a pain and error-prone. It only gets worse as the HTML gets more complex, especially when you don't control the generation of the content.