# Prime generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a prime generator, which is different from anyone in this link

[generator in Python generating prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706911/generator-in-python-generating-prime-numbers)

Here is my code

```
def sequence():
    i = 1 
    while True:
        i += 2
        yield i

def prime_generator(n):
    i = 2
   it = sequence()
    while i < n:
        it= filter(lambda x: x % i, it)
        i = next(it)
        yield i
```

when i run something like

```
for i in prime_generator(50):
    print(i)
```

It never dump 15, 33, sth like that for me. In a word, It gives me 2 and all odd numbers. what goes wrong here?

Comment: Uhm, 15 isn't prime. Neither is 33.

Comment: On the other hand, all odd numbers show up. *Interesting*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `i` inside the lambda isn't "fixed"; when `i` changes in the outside scope, the previously created lambda functions all use the new value, and so they all do the same check: see if the current value from `sequence()` is divisible by the last found prime. Which they never are.

Wrapping it into another `lambda` and then calling it so that the value of `i` can be fixed works:

```
def prime_generator(n):
    i = 2
    it = sequence()
    while i < n:
        it = (lambda i: filter(lambda x: x % i, it))(i)
        i = next(it)
        yield i
```

Edit: also I don't believe your code (nor this) does yield 2, but that can be trivially fixed.

Comment: Rather than wrapping it in another lambda you could use a default argument: `it = filter(lambda x, i=i: x % i, it)`

Comment: Sure, but I prefer the default arg method rather than using a closure because it's more compact, it's flatter, and in my tests it tends to run a little faster.

Comment: The nice thing about the default argument solution is that it becomes a local variable in the function (I think), and they have super fast lookups, so that will definitely help. But it feels slightly wrong to me to have a default argument that will never be used as a real argument and it's only a stack overflow answer to a hobby question, so I'll stick to what looks cleanest to me :-)