# Iterating until a function returns True a user defined number of times

Tags: python

I've written a function, isprime(n), that returns True if a number is prime and false if not.
I am able to loop the function a defined number of times; but I can't figure out how to iterate until it finds x number of primes. I feel as though I have a decent understanding of For and While loops, but am confused as to how one integrates boolean return values into loops. Here is my current code and error:

Error result:

```
input:100
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "euler7.py", line 25, in <module>
primeList += 1
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

And the code:

```
def isprime(n):
    x = 2
    while x < sqrt(n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
        else:
            x += 1
    return True

userinput = int(raw_input('input:'))

primeList = []
primesFound = 0

while primesFound != userinput:
    i = 2
    if isprime(i):
        primeList.append(i)
        primeList += 1
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

EDIT (including the updated and functioning code):

```
from math import sqrt
def isprime(n):
    x = 2
    while x < (sqrt(n) + 1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
        else:
            x += 1
    return True

userinput = int(raw_input('input:'))
primeList = []
primeList.append(2)

i = 2
while len(primeList) != userinput:
    if isprime(i):
        primeList.append(i)
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1

print 'result:', primeList[-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out:

- You should increment `primesFound`, not `primeList`.
- The `isprime()` function has a bug -- and returns `True` for 9. You need `sqrt(n) + 1`.

In addition:

- You need to initialize `i` outside the `while` loop; otherwise, you simply build up a list of 2's.
- There is no need for `primesFound`. Just check `len(primeList)`.

And my pet peeve:

- Command-line programs should resort to interactive user input only in special circumstances. Where possible, take parameters as command-line arguments or options. For example: `userinput = int(sys.argv[1])`.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
primeList += 1
```

Should be:

```
primesFound += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add and `int` to a python `list`. You should do `primesFound += 1` to achieve your desired result.

Plus, your `isprime` function is wrong. It will return `True` for 9. You should do `while x < sqrt(n) + 1` for the `while` loop of your `isprime` function.

So you should have:

```
def isprime(n):
    x=2
    while x < sqrt(n) +1:
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
        else:
            x += 1
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `n` numbers that satisfy some condition, you could use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function and a generator expression:

```
from itertools import count, islice

n = int(raw_input('number of primes:'))
primes = list(islice((p for p in count(2) if isprime(p)), n))
```

where `(p for p in count(2) if isprime(p))` is a generator expression that produces prime numbers indefinitely (it could also be written as `itertools.ifilter(isprime, count(2))`).

You could use [Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), to get a more efficient solution:

```
def primes_upto(limit):
    """Yield prime numbers less than `limit`."""
    isprime = [True] * limit
    for n in xrange(2, limit):
        if isprime[n]:
           yield n
           for m in xrange(n*n, limit, n): # mark multiples of n as composites
               isprime[m] = False

print list(primes_upto(60))
# -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59]
```

See [Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/4279).

Note: there are about `limit / (log(limit) - 1)` prime numbers less than `limit`.

You could also use an infinite prime number generator such as [`gen_primes()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212923/4279), to get the first `n` primes numbers:

```
primes = list(islice(gen_primes(), n))
```

See [How to implement an efficient infinite generator of prime numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2211990/4279)

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(n):
    x=2
    while x < sqrt(n) +1:
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
            break
        else:
            x += 1
    return True
```