# While looping issue in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python

Using Python 3.5.1.

I am trying to build a while loop, which iterates a function until a certain number of prime numbers has been appended into a list. I have previously written a function which takes in a number, evaluates whether or not it is a prime and adds it to a list if it is a prime:

```
def primelister(n):
    if n < 10:
            return
    else:
            l1=[]
            l2=[]
            ts1=np.arange(1,(n+1),1)
            for i in ts1:
                    if n%i==0:
                            l1.append(i)
                            continue
                    else:
                            continue
            if len(l1) < 3:
                    l2.append(i)
                    print(l2)
```

This function works ok and seems to give out correct results. I would like to implement the function in to a while loop, where the value of n starts out at 10, and is incremented by 1 at each loop. The loop would go on until a certain number of primes has been reached (i.e. stop when 1000 primes have been listed).

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    n=10
    l1=[]
    l2=[]

    while numberofprimes < 100:
           ts1=np.arange(1,(n+1),1)
           for i in ts1:
                  if n%i==0:
                         l1.append(i)
                         continue
           if len(l1) < 3:
                  l2.append(i)
           numofprimes=len(l2)
           print("Number of primes so far:", numberofprimes)
           n = n + 1
```

The loop is obviously broken. The output is just 1 at all times, and the loop seems to be infinite. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to reset `l1` each iteration. Move `l1=[]` into the loop.

Comment: if you would like to see a really fast and smart implementation of the solution please check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628949/to-find-first-n-prime-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not resetting `l1` after each while loop iteration. Furthermore, you are using `numberofprimes` as your while loop condition while assigning the number of primes value to `numofprimes`

```
import numpy as NP
n=10
l2=[]
numberofprimes = 0
while numberofprimes < 100:
    l1 = []
    ts1=NP.arange(1,(n+1),1)
    for i in ts1:
       if n%i==0:
            l1.append(i)
    if len(l1) < 3:
       l2.append(i)
    numberofprimes=len(l2)
    print("Number of primes so far:", numberofprimes)
    n = n + 1
```