# Project Euler #10 Java solution not working

Tags: java, math, primes

I'm trying to find the sum of the prime numbers < 2,000,000. This is my solution in Java but I can't seem get the correct answer. Please give some input on what could be wrong and general advice on the code is appreciated.

Printing 'sum' gives: 1308111344, which is incorrect.

Edit: 
Thanks for all the help. Changed int to long and < to <= and it worked flawlessly, except for being an inefficient way of finding prime numbers :)

```
/*
The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
Find the sum of all the primes below two million.
*/
class Helper{
 public void run(){
  Integer sum = 0;
  for(int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++){
   if(isPrime(i))
    sum += i;   
  }
  System.out.println(sum);
 }

 private boolean isPrime(int nr){
  if(nr == 2)
   return true;
  else if(nr == 1)
   return false;
  if(nr % 2 == 0)
   return false;

  for(int i = 3; i < Math.sqrt(nr); i += 2){
   if(nr % i == 0)
    return false;
  }  
  return true;  
 }
}   
class Problem{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Helper p = new Helper();
p.run();
}
}
```

Comment: as a hint there , i would put the Math.sqrt(nr) outside the for condition, so i wouldn't be evaluated every time in every loop
like: stop = Math.sqrt(nr) (a ceil could be used too, to avoid float rounding errors)
for(int i = 3; i< stop; i+=2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result will be too large to fit into an integer, so you are getting an [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow). Try using a [BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or a [long](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) instead. In this case a long is enough.

Comment: That's not the problem, or at least not the only problem.

Comment: A long would be better [faster] than a BigInteger.  It's obviously large enough since 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 2000000 = 2000001000000 which is smaller than the max of a long.

Comment: @Pointy: Of the two mistakes this one is the one that gives the largest magnitude error. But both mistakes cause the answer to be wrong. Unfortunately there is no way to accept two answers so if you want you can copy my answer into yours and accept the glory. ;)

Comment: Yes you're right; I wasn't sure whether it'd squeeze in but another 1/2 cup of coffee and I did the basic math.  When I did those Project Euler problems I used Erlang, so I never had to worry about integer sizes (all Erlang integers are like "BigInteger") :-)

Answer (score 6):

You're treating as prime those numbers that are only divisible by their square root (like 25). Instead of `i < Math.sqrt(nr)` try `i <= Math.sqrt(nr)`.

That's a really inefficient way to find primes, incidentally.

Comment: Whoa why the drive-by downvote?  The algorithm is in fact wrong, for the reason I state here.

Comment: Wrong. He's looping from 3 to the square root of the number.
If the number is, let's say 25 - you don't need to check anything higher than 5. If there is divisor higher than 5 - then the other divisor will be lower than five, and would've been checked in the beginning of the loop.

Comment: He's **not** looping to the square root!! The comparison he uses is `<` not `<=`.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I slightly misunderstood your response. Sorry, inverted my vote :D

Answer (score 3):

Your isPrime doesn't work for squares. isPrime(9) returns true.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated errors were two:

- you used an `int` that is not big enough to hold that sum.. you should have used a `long`
- you used `<` instead that `<=`, and it was a wrong guard for the cycle

Apart from that what you are doing is really inefficient, without going too deep inside this class of algorithms (like **Miller-Rabin** test) I would suggest you to take a look to the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).. a really old approach that teaches how to treat a complex problem in a simple manner to improve elegance and efficiency with a trade-off of memory.

It's really cleaver: it keeps track of a `boolean` value for every prime up to your 2 millions that asserts if that number is prime or not. Then starting from the first prime it excludes all the successive numbers that are obtained by multiplying the prime it is analyzing for another number. Of couse more it goes and less numbers it will have to check (since it already excluded them)

Code is fair simple (just wrote it on the fly, didn't check it):

```
    boolean[] numbers = new boolean[2000000];
    long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        numbers[i] = true;

    for (int i = 2; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        if (!numbers[i])
            continue;
        else {
            int j = i + i;
            while (j < 2000000) {                   
                numbers[j] = false;
                j += i;
            }           
        }

    for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; ++i)
        sum += numbers[i] ? i : 0;

    System.out.println(sum);
```

Of course this approach is still unsuitable for high numbers (because it has to find all the previous primes anyway and because of memory) but it's a good example for starters to think about problems..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers/1043247#1043247

Comment: using a bitset is a really nice idea, I would like to have the good old JIT java compiler to do these optimization by itself :)

Comment: Also note that it starts eliminating multiples at `i * i`, all multiples below that must have been eliminated by a smaller factor. This is a big gain.

Answer (score 1):

by using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) effectively, i solved the problem, here is my code

```
public class SumOfPrime {

    static void findSum()
    {
        long i=3;
        long sum=0;
        int count=0;
        boolean[] array = new boolean[2000000];
        for(long j=0;j<array.length;j++)
        {
         if((j&1)==0)
          array[(int)j]=false;   
         else    
         array[(int)j]=true;
        }
        array[1]=false;
        array[2]=true;
        for(;i<2000000;i+=2)
        { 
            if(array[(int)i] & isPrime(i))
            {   
                array[(int)i]=true;
                //Sieve of Eratosthenes
                for(long j=i+i;j<array.length;j+=i)
                    array[(int)j]=false;
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if(array[j])
            {   
             //System.out.println(j);
             count++;   
             sum+=j;
            }
        }   
        System.out.println("Sum="+sum +" Count="+count);
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(long num)
    {
        boolean flag=false;
        long i=3;
        long limit=(long)Math.sqrt(num);
        for(;i<limit && !(flag);i+=2)
        {
            if(num%i==0)
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(i>=limit)
         flag=true;
        return flag;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        findSum();
        long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time for execution="+(end-start)+"ms");
    }

}
```

and the output is

```
Sum=142913828922 Count=148933
Time for execution=2360ms
```

if you have doubt, please do tell

Comment: You could store twice as much booleans in the same space by ignoring the even numbers. It requires only some arithmatic to resolve to the correct index. Also, since boolean uses a whole byte for storage, you're wasting a lot of space. You can better use a bitarray:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
  public class ProjectEuler {

    public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
        if (i < 2) {
            return false;
        } else if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            for (int j = 3; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j = j + 2) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }


    public static long sumOfAllPrime(int number){
        long sum = 2;

        for (int i = 3; i <= number; i += 2) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumOfAllPrime(2000000));
    }
}
```