# Is there a publically available table of prime numbers in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, primes

I know there is one which is used in all kind of .NET dictionaries and hashtables in:

`internal static class HashHelpers`

- Is there a public one somwhere else as well?
- If no, why is it kept internal isn't it something very commonly used?
- Is the copy & paste the way to go if I need prime numbers in my code?

Comment: "why is it kept internal" - I guess so they're free to change the internal implementation of those classes without needing to keep it around for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: Prime numbers will remain compatible forever I guess :D

Comment: Correct, but the signature of the method may need to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As far as I know, there is no public version of that table available in .NET
2. Because this table is not a table of all prime numbers in a range, but rather a table of arbitrarily chosen subset of prime numbers suitable for a particular purpose (sizing hash-based containers)
3. No, you should either generate your own table on the fly, or copy-paste a table from one of many *complete* sources.

Comment: 2. Was new for me - I think it explains why it's not public.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot answer your question regarding the availability of HashHelpers, but here are ways of implementing it yourself.

Here a post with some imperative implementations on generating prime numbers:
[Most elegant way to generate prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers)

Additionally, you can do it in LINQ:

```
var odds =
    from n in Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    select 3 + (long) n * 2;

var primes = (new[] { 2L }).Concat(
    from p in odds
    where ! odds.TakeWhile(odd => odd * odd <= p).Any(odd => p % odd == 0)
    select p);
```

Source: http://jacobcarpenter.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/linq-to-prime-numbers/

Edit:  Don't use int.MaxValue in your initial range.  Limit this to something appropriate.

Comment: This is one of the most beautiful piece of code to generate primes that I've seen, but it is definitely not the most performant. It performs far more checks than it needs to. A better alternative would be to use only the primes that we've already found as candidate divisors.

Comment: The question was not about "how to generate prime numbers in .net" - the main point of my question was **having a table of precalculeted primes** to use in hasing, encyption etc. algorithms - in order to save time for their calculation.

Comment: @achitaka-san - if you can generate the primes it's pretty trivial to put them in a static array.  If you want, you can even write them into a text file [formatted as a C# array] than C&P this into your code file.  THINK MAN THINK!