# Very simple prime number test - I think I'm not understanding the for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iterator, primes

I am practicing past exam papers for a basic java exam, and I am finding it difficult to make a for loop work for testing whether a number is prime. I don't want to complicate it by adding efficiency measures for larger numbers, just something that would at least work for 2 digit numbers.

At the moment it always returns false even if n IS a prime number.

I think my problem is that I am getting something wrong with the for loop itself and where to put the "return true;" and "return false;"... I'm sure it's a really basic mistake I'm making...

```
public boolean isPrime(int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The reason I couldn't find help elsewhere on stackoverflow is because similar questions were asking for a more complicated implementation to have a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Hmm, I tested it with the number 15 which is an odd, non-prime number, and it came back false, which is correct. So it does seem to be working...

Comment: and if you were to test it with 3 which is an odd prime number, it would come back false too, which is incorrect. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your `for` loop has a little problem. It should be: -

```
for (i = 2; i < n; i++)  // replace `i <= n` with `i < n`
```

Of course you don't want to check the remainder when `n` is divided by `n`. It will always give you `1`.

In fact, you can even reduce the number of iterations by changing the condition to: - `i <= n / 2`. Since `n` can't be divided by a number greater than `n / 2`, except when we consider `n`, which we don't have to consider at all.

So, you can change your `for` loop to: -

```
for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else who pointed this out! I can't believe I didn't spot this : )

Answer (score 32):

You can stop much earlier and skip through the loop faster with:

```
public boolean isPrime(long n) {
    // fast even test.
    if(n > 2 && (n & 1) == 0)
       return false;
    // only odd factors need to be tested up to n^0.5
    for(int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        if (n % i == 0) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: BTW 2 is a Prime number ;)

Comment: @VishalK Which is why I have a "fast even test" ;)

Comment: But isn’t `(2 & 1) == 0`? So `isPrime(2) == false`, which is false.

Comment: I forgot that all even numbers except 2 are non prime.

Comment: Note that a sieve is much faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers/1043247#1043247

Comment: @starblue sieve is much faster if you need a collection of prime numbers.  If you want to test just one prime number, this search is much faster.

Comment: `i*i <= n` may overflow, that's not a good solution. Better calculate `sqrt(n)` before the loop and compare against it.

Comment: @Archie That is highly unlikely as `n` would have to be greater than the largest square you can represent with a `long` whereas sqrt(n) equally has round errors for such large `long` values. i.e. it can fail with much smaller numbers. It could be faster for large values.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well, it's Java; `long` is 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits. And `sqrt(max_long) > max_int`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am inline with using sqrt(n) before the loop suggested by Archie, at least this will avoid finding the square on each iteration. sqrt(n) is one time computation for the whole iteration.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar it is but also it's very expensive. As `i * i` can be done concurrently with `n % i` you would need to do a micro -benchmark to see if it really helped.

Answer (score 3):

You should write `i < n`, because the last iteration step will give you `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Error is i<=n

```
for (i = 2; i<n; i++){
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PrimeNumberCheck {
  private static int maxNumberToCheck = 100;

  public PrimeNumberCheck() {
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      PrimeNumberCheck primeNumberCheck = new PrimeNumberCheck();

      for(int ii=0;ii < maxNumberToCheck; ii++) {
        boolean isPrimeNumber = primeNumberCheck.isPrime(ii);

      System.out.println(ii + " is " + (isPrimeNumber == true ? "prime." : "not prime."));
    }
  }

  private boolean isPrime(int numberToCheck) {    
    boolean isPrime = true;

    if(numberToCheck < 2) {
      isPrime = false;
    }

    for(int ii=2;ii<numberToCheck;ii++) {
      if(numberToCheck%ii == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    return isPrime;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code number divisible by 3 will be skipped the for loop code initialization. 
For loop iteration will also skip multiples of 3.

```
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {

    if ((n > 2 && (n & 1) == 0) // check is it even
       || n <= 1  //check for -ve
       || (n > 3 && (n % 3 ==  0))) {  //check for 3 divisiable
            return false;
    }

    int maxLookup = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 3; (i+2) <= maxLookup; i = i + 6) {
        if (n % (i+2) == 0 || n % (i+4) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why till sqrt? Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VPA-HjjUmU&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLL-mEB4ef20f3iqWMGWa25&index=3

Answer (score 1):

You could also use some simple Math property for this in your for loop.

A number 'n' will be a prime number if and only if it is divisible by itself or 1. 
If a number is not a prime number it will have two factors:

```
n = a * b
```

you can use the for loop to check till sqrt of the number 'n' instead of going all the way to 'n'. As in if 'a' and 'b' both are greater than the sqrt of the number 'n', a*b would be greater than 'n'. So at least one of the factors must be less than or equal to the square root.

so your loop would be something like below:

```
for(int i=2; i<=Math.sqrt(n); i++)
```

By doing this you would drastically reduce the run time complexity of the code.
I think it would come down to O(n/2).

Answer (score 1):

One of the fastest way is looping only till the square root of n.

```
  private static boolean isPrime(int n){
        int square = (int)Math.ceil((Math.sqrt(n)));//find the square root
        HashSet<Integer> nos = new HashSet<>(); 
        for(int i=1;i<=square;i++){
            if(n%i==0){
                if(n/i==i){
                    nos.add(i);
                }else{
                    nos.add(i);
                    int rem = n/i;
                    nos.add(rem);
                }
            }
        }
        return nos.size()==2;//if contains 1 and n then prime
    }
```

Comment: Hm, maybe it's faster (is it?), but it makes HashSet that might grow quite considerably...

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `i<=n`.So when `i==n`, you will get 0 only and it will return false always.Try `i<=(n/2)`.No need to check until `i<n`.

Comment: The check will be i less than OR EQUAL TO n.

Comment: The maximum number that can be a factor of n is n/2.

Comment: Maximum number that can be factor should be check till `sqrt(n)` not `(n/2)` since if `n/2` will be factor then it means `n = n/2 * 2` , so `2` will also be factor and would be detected earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned above algorithm treats 1 as prime though it is not. 
Hence here is the solution.

```
static boolean isPrime(int n) {
  int perfect_modulo = 0;
  boolean prime = false;

  for ( int i = 1; i <=  n; i++ ) {
    if ( n % i == 0 ) {
      perfect_modulo += 1;
    }
  }
  if ( perfect_modulo == 2 ) {
    prime = true;
  }

  return prime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the Java 8 way is nicer and cleaner

```
    private static boolean isPrimeA(final int number) {
        return IntStream
               .rangeClosed(2, number/2)
               .noneMatch(i -> number%i == 0);
    }
```