# getting all prime numbers

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple C# console application that gets all prime numbers, and stacks them into a string variable.

My question is why does the first "if" accept all the numbers? I think the rule I wrote is fine. My code (of course all the variables are formatted in the head of the script):

```
check++;
number++;
num = number;
if (number / num == 1 && number / 1 == num)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working...");
    Console.WriteLine("Numbers Checked: " + check);

    produce++;
    Console.WriteLine("Numbers Prodused: " + produce);


    Console.WriteLine("Numbers Failed : " + fail);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    Console.Clear();

    //storing the numbers
    str += Convert.ToString(number);
}
else
{
    fail++;
}
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The problem is that when I run the program, the fail indicator stays on 0 which means the loop is processing all the numbers with no exception for the prime numbers.

How do I fix that? Is my "if (rule)" wrong?

---

**EDIT ! :**

i started fresh ;)
here's what i did:

```
        bool isPrime = false;
        int number = 0, counter = 0;

        while (number <= counter)
        {
            counter++;
            number++;
            isPrime = true;
            for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                Console.WriteLine(number);
                Console.Beep();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Try Number " + counter);
```

works great, I'll continue developing it into a windows forms application soon ;)

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: You should loop to `i<number/2` since you already checked if it divisible by two. See similar post http://stackoverflow.com/q/15743192/380384

Comment: Before making your Forms App, read wikipedia on primes, e.g.: *The most basic primality testing routine, trial division, is too slow to be useful for large numbers.*

Answer (score 4):

```
 num = number;
        if (number / num == 1 && number / 1 == num)
        {
```

Let's assume `number` is equal to `10`.

```
num = number = 10;

if(10 / 10 == 1 && 10 / 1 == 10) {
    // This is called a constant positive.
}
```

`num` and `number` are always the same, so we could say in a more mathematical sense

```
for all a,b where a == b.

a/b = 1
a/1 = b
```

This means that no matter the value of `number`, you're always going to evaluate to `true` in your `if statement`.

**What you want to do**

You should look a little closer into [how you define a prime number](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/prime-number.html). At the moment you're saying the following:

> Some integer, a, is considered prime *if and only if* it can be divided by 1 and itself.

You also need to prove that it can't be divided by numbers less than it too!

**so..**

Whereas the approach you *can* take is the certain method, where you check *all* `0 << i << a` (between 0 and the current number), or you can use some of the more interesting methods which will work out if the number is a `probabilistic prime`. That is, we're not `certain` that it is a prime number, but there is a very high chance that it is.

For certain primes, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650360/very-simple-prime-number-test-i-think-im-not-understanding-the-for-loop), and when you are feeling more confident try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

For probabilistic primes, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests). This will give you an explanation of many different algorithms.

Comment: i started fresh ;)
here's what i did:

Answer (score 3):

This makes absolutely no sense. Let's break down these lines:

```
num = number;
if (number / num == 1 && number / 1 == num)
```

Since you set `num = number`, `number / num` will *always* be 1, so the left side evaluates to true *always*.

The right part doesn't even make sense. Dividing by 1 does absolutely nothing, so `number / 1` is just `number`. Now, all you really have is `number == num`, and since you set `num` and `number` as the same, that also evaluates to true.

You might as well just write `if (true)`.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Because every number divided by 1 is the number it self.
and Why number and `num` are equal ? because the row before the if condition assign `num` as `number`.

Answer (score 0):

num = number;
you are setting num equal to number each time before if condition is applied