# clear all the multiples of a index in a bitset in Java?

Tags: java, iteration, primes, bitset

I have a bitSet and I want to turn off all the multiples of a given index.
eg: given a `bitset -- > {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17}`, I want to `iterate` through the `bitset` and turn off the multiples of each of them. In the end, I should have `{1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17}` which are nothing but prime numbers. so far I have:

```
public static void getPrimeNumbers(int n) {
    BitSet s = new BitSet();
    // s.set(0);
    s.set(1);
    s.set(2);
    //create the set having all numbers till n
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
        s.set(i);
    }
            //for element in Bitset ....
    //need to clear multiple of bits in iteration   
    }
```

need a little help here, I should be able to pick up from there..

Comment: you could use a while loop or a for loop and check if `(s.get(i))`, then do `s.clear()`.

Comment: Except that `1` isn't prime and all the other numbers are multiples of `1`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1043247/49246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do some thing like this:

```
//you start from 3 because 1 and 2 are prime already   
int i = 3;
//you can do square check, since you would have turned off all bits before you reach n
while (i * i < n) {
        if (s.get(i)) {
            int k = 3 * i;
            while (k <= n) {
                s.clear(k);
                k += i;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

or you can look at the next turned bit and turn off all its multiples:

```
for (int j = s.nextSetBit(3);j>=0;j=s.nextSetBit(j+1)){
            int k =3 * j;
            while (k <= n){
                s.clear(k);
                k+=j;
            }
        }
```

here, the [nextsetBit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit%28int%29) would give you the next turned on bit at or after a specified index. you increment, every position, by a factor of bit index, so that all its turned off. In each `while loop`, you are turning off the multiples of bit index. this is nothing but `sieve` logic, more details you can find in wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Port the sieve of "Sieve of Eratosthenes" algorithm to your structure (BitSet).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Should be straightforward enough.

Here is a Java implementation using an array.
Just port it to BitSet.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/PrimeSieve.java.html